# MongoDB charts to MongoDB NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So according to MongoDB charts the code I need to replicate the chart is the following (below) however when I copy and paste the code into my NodeJS app it throws an error.

See below.

How do I get this to work in my NodeJS code.

```
{
    "isFetching": false,
    "isOpen": true,
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          "campaignID": {
            "$oid": "629d7fb4b0697d84aa7043ee"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "__alias_0": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$isArray": "$history"
              },
              "then": {
                "$size": "$history"
              },
              "else": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "timeplay": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$timeplay"
                  },
                  "date"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$timeplay",
              "else": null
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "__alias_1": {
            "year": {
              "$year": "$timeplay"
            },
            "month": {
              "$subtract": [
                {
                  "$month": "$timeplay"
                },
                1
              ]
            },
            "date": {
              "$dayOfMonth": "$timeplay"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "__alias_1": "$__alias_1"
          },
          "__alias_0": {
            "$sum": "$__alias_0"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "__alias_1": "$_id.__alias_1",
          "__alias_0": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "x": "$__alias_1",
          "y": "$__alias_0",
          "_id": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "x.year": 1,
          "x.month": 1,
          "x.date": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$limit": 5000
      }
    ]
  }
```

However when I try and run it I get

```
error - MongoInvalidArgumentError: Argument "pipeline" must be an array of aggregation stages
```

Should the code not be working, as this is what MongoDB own system says it is correct code? all I did was copy and paste the code they supplied. [image: screenshot from MongoDB]

Full code:

```
import clientPromise from "../../../../lib/mongodb";
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb'

export default async function overview(req, res) {
    //CONNECT

    const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
    let client
    let clientPromise
    const options = {}
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    clientPromise = client.connect()
    const clients = await clientPromise
    const database = clients.db('DATABASE');
    const nowplayingstats = await database.collection('NowPlaying');

    //END CONNECT
  //    res.send("YES I WORKED "+total);
  const search = await nowplayingstats.aggregate({
    "isFetching": false,
    "isOpen": true,
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          "campaignID": {
            "$oid": "629d7fb4b0697d84aa7043ee"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "__alias_0": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$isArray": "$history"
              },
              "then": {
                "$size": "$history"
              },
              "else": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "timeplay": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$timeplay"
                  },
                  "date"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$timeplay",
              "else": null
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "__alias_1": {
            "year": {
              "$year": "$timeplay"
            },
            "month": {
              "$subtract": [
                {
                  "$month": "$timeplay"
                },
                1
              ]
            },
            "date": {
              "$dayOfMonth": "$timeplay"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "__alias_1": "$__alias_1"
          },
          "__alias_0": {
            "$sum": "$__alias_0"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "__alias_1": "$_id.__alias_1",
          "__alias_0": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "x": "$__alias_1",
          "y": "$__alias_0",
          "_id": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "x.year": 1,
          "x.month": 1,
          "x.date": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$limit": 5000
      }
    ]
  }).toArray();
  
    res.json(search)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, take everything from pipeline and nothing else.

Code ended up being

```
[
      {
        "$match": {
          "campaignID": {
            "$oid": "629d7fb4b0697d84aa7043ee"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "__alias_0": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$isArray": "$history"
              },
              "then": {
                "$size": "$history"
              },
              "else": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "timeplay": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$timeplay"
                  },
                  "date"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$timeplay",
              "else": null
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "__alias_1": {
            "year": {
              "$year": "$timeplay"
            },
            "month": {
              "$subtract": [
                {
                  "$month": "$timeplay"
                },
                1
              ]
            },
            "date": {
              "$dayOfMonth": "$timeplay"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "__alias_1": "$__alias_1"
          },
          "__alias_0": {
            "$sum": "$__alias_0"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "__alias_1": "$_id.__alias_1",
          "__alias_0": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "x": "$__alias_1",
          "y": "$__alias_0",
          "_id": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "x.year": 1,
          "x.month": 1,
          "x.date": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$limit": 5000
      }
    ]
```